# Confluence REST API content-type issue for attachment with python

Tags: python, python-requests, confluence-rest-api, http-status-code-415

I am trying to upload an attachment to Confluence using REST API from python. I get 415 error: unsupported media type.

I understand the content-type is not correct, but I tried some content types and got the same error:

```
import requests
print("start....................")
url = 'https://confluence.XXX.com/confluence/rest/api/content/' + str(108458915) + '/child/attachment/'
TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXX'
headers = {'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {TOKEN}"
        } #no content-type here!
file = 'my_file.jpeg'
content_type = 'multipart/form-data'
files = {'file': (file, open(file, 'rb'), content_type)}

print("request....................")

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files=files, verify='confluence.XXX.crt')
r.raise_for_status()
```

I tried the following content-types: `'image/jpeg'` `'application/json'` `'application/xml'` `'application/octet-stream'` `'multipart/form-data'` but get the same 415 error:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 415 Client Error:  for url:
> https://confluence.XXX.com/rest/api/content/108458915/child/attachment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find what is the problem with my first code, but the following code fixed the issue:

```
import requests

url = "https://confluence.XXX.com/rest/api/content/108458915/child/attachment"
certificate = 'confluence_certificate.cer'
TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXX'


files = {'file': ('my_file.jpeg', open('my_file.jpeg', 'rb'))}
headers = {'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check',
                              'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}"}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, verify=certificate)

print(response.status_code)
print(response)
```